# Как для каждого пользователя получить данные из одной таблицы и сумму значений по столбцу из другой таблицы?

Tags: mysql, sql

Написал следующий запрос:

```
SELECT bookkeep.user.iduser, bookkeep.user.Name,
(SELECT SUM(Count) FROM bookkeep.moneyout) 
FROM bookkeep.user
```

Проблема этого запроса в том, что он суммирует все значения столбца `count` и присваивает обоим людям как на скриншоте. А мне нужно, например, чтобы суммировались значения столбца для каждого человека отдельно.

[image: Итог запроса]

[image: Таблица для выборки]

Comment: Прочтите пожалуйста ещё раз заголовок. Вы его понимаете?

Comment: @0xdb я не сообразил как корректно написать заголоволок но ниже я описал суть проблемы.

Comment: Вы забли where в подзапросе, вот оно и считает полную сумму для каждого юзера.

Comment: @0xdb я на счет where и думаю. Изначально думал сделать что-то вроде idRecord=idUser однако тогда у нас выведется только самая первая строка,а есть еще пользователь под id 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  t.iduser, t.Name, SUM(t2.Count)
FROM bookkeep.user as t
LEFT JOIN bookkeep.moneyout as t2 on t2.idUser = t.iduser
GROUP by t.iduser
```

Answer (score 1):

можно попробывать так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.user_id, 
                t.user_name, 
                SUM(t2.moneyout_count) OVER(PARTITION BY t2.user_id)
FROM testik.users as t
LEFT JOIN testik.moneyout as t2 on t2.user_id = t.user_id;
```